# help me my server seems to be sending spam!

Tags: security, mail-server

Running on Ubuntu 18, pretty recently installed server (started a couple of weeks ago, installation is not yet finished...). Trying to setup a simple mail server to send mail from php and host a few mail accounts for my domains.

However something is very wrong. When doing tail -f /var/log/mail.log I see LOTS of activity in there. I'm not sure all that I am seeing is actually email being sent out or if some of it is just people trying to spam through my server unsuccessfully, but anyways its writing like hundreds of entries per minute at least!

I also setup the option to have every mail sent by PHP logged in a separate log and I have maybe around 10 emails sent by PHP a day, so it seems the spam does not originate from insecure PHP scripts.

My mail.log is showing lines shuch as these:

Mar 10 21:24:26 server1 postfix/smtp[29358]: B111954079F: to=, relay=mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net[212.82.101.46]:25, delay=227210, delays=227209/0.01/0.88/0.1, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (host mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net[212.82.101.46] said: 421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from *x.x.x.x* temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN3434.html (in reply to MAIL FROM command))

(x.x.x.x was my ip there)

This has been going on for days. What can be sending all those emails from (or through) my server? How? How to stop it?

Can I stop all emails not being sent by PHP somehow and just use a webmail?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that spam is sent through the site, or injected into the site.

I recommend shutdown smtp and find place where spam is sending.

Assume this place in your php project.